# Laravel get one field by another field value from collection

Tags: php, mysql, collections, laravel-5

I have two tables in database and in my view i get the collection of both tables

```
Route::get('/', function () {
$workers = \App\worker::get();
$process = \App\Process::get();
return view('welcome')->with('workers', $workers)->with('process', $process);
});
```

And from this you see that i have `process` and `workers`, and in my `welcome.blade.php` at one stage i have to list the `title` of all `process` that are associated with selected `workers`

So in my database table `worker` i have one field named `process` and it's saved in a string with `ID` number of associated `process` for that worker delimited with `|`. So `$worker->process` returns `1|21` for example this means that worker is associated with process id 1 and 21 in `process` database.

The problem is that `$process` returns array collection with all data and since array have it's own list starting with `0` if i delete and add new `process` the array id doesn't match the `ID` of process.

Here is the loop that i have in my blade template

```
@foreach (explode("|", $worker->process) as $id)
   '<h4>{{ $process->title }}</h4>'
@endforeach
```

So this will return the title of whole different process. what i basically need to select process by `$process->id` and return `$process->title`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works

```
$process->find($id)->title
```

As i understood from search this finds item by field id